# Multiple onClick of a button in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout where I display the values as below:

[image]

Now I am able to achieve on row click, but I have three buttons in each row.

On click on Start, Completed and Delivered I need to update a column (Status) in mysql table.
If it was just a table row we could have done it like this:

```
tr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View pos) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Row clicked: " + pos.getId());
            }
        });
```

Below is my code for table layout:

```
/*******getting values from mysql db  and assigning it to teach row***********/
try{
            allarray = new JSONArray(result);
            System.out.println("array is " +allarray.length());
            JSONObject json_data=null;
                for(int j=0;j<allarray.length();j++){
                json_data = allarray.getJSONObject(j);
                json_data.getString("PreparationLot");
                json_data.getString("Prep_MenuItem");
                json_data.getString("Prep_Quantity");
                json_data.getString("Prep_Order_Number");
                json_data.getString("Prep_Notes");

                TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

                TableRow tr = new TableRow(DashBoard.this);
                if(count%2!=0) {
                    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(222, 219, 219));
                }else{
                    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                }
                tr.setId(20);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams());

                TextView lotno = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                lotno.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                lotno.setText(""+json_data.getString("PreparationLot")); // set the text for the header 
                lotno.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                lotno.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                lotno.setTextSize(18);
                tr.addView(lotno);

                TextView itemname = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                itemname.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                itemname.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_MenuItem")); // set the text for the header 
                itemname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                itemname.setPadding(30, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                itemname.setTextSize(18);
                tr.addView(itemname);

                TextView qty = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                qty.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                qty.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_Quantity")); // set the text for the header 
                qty.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                qty.setPadding(70, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                qty.setTextSize(18);
                tr.addView(qty);

                TextView order = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                order.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                order.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_Order_Number")); // set the text for the header 
                order.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                order.setPadding(60, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                order.setTextSize(18);
                tr.addView(order);

                TextView notes = new TextView(DashBoard.this);
                notes.setId(200+count);// define id that must be unique
                notes.setText(""+json_data.getString("Prep_Notes")); // set the text for the header 
                notes.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                notes.setPadding(60, 10, 0, 10); // set the padding (if required)
                notes.setTextSize(18);
                tr.addView(notes);

                Button start = new Button(DashBoard.this);
                start.setText("Start");
                start.setMaxWidth(10);
                tr.addView(start); 

                Button complete = new Button(DashBoard.this);
                complete.setText("Complete");
                complete.setMaxWidth(10);
                tr.addView(complete); 

                Button delivered = new Button(DashBoard.this);
                delivered.setText("Delivered");
                delivered.setMaxWidth(10);
                tr.addView(delivered); 

                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

           count++;
           tr.setClickable(true);
           tr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View pos) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  Toast.makeText(DashBoard.this, v.getId(), 1000).show();
                System.out.println("Row clicked: " + pos.getId());
            }
        });
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e1){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No data Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

**Problem:** *if I click on Start, Completed or Delivered I need to update that row's status. How to do it?*

Comment: Please include your design xml file

Comment: @kittu88 i am adding the table layout progrmatically

Comment: Set a `OnClickListener` for all your `Buttons` from the `TableRows`. In the `onClick` method of that listener: `TableRow tr = (TableRow)v.getParent();`. Then you can use `tr` with `findViewById` to get any other `View` from that `Button`'s row to update it.

Comment: I guess you can add button IDs and create on click listener on the basis of them

Comment: @Luksprog u mean to say in the tr.onclick() method i need to add onclick on buttons?

Comment: No, when you create them you set their own `OnClickListener`. For example: `Button start = new Button(DashBoard.this); start.setOnClickListener(mListener);` where `mListener` is the `OnCLickListener`.

Comment: @Luksprog mListener is what can u please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem: if I click on Start, Completed or Delivered I need to update
>   that row's status. How to do it?

First, I don't know what do you understand from updating the row's status. If you want to "see" click events for any of the `Buttons` in any of the `TableRows` create a single `OnCLickListener` :

```
private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent();
        // now you have a reference to the row where this Button that was
        // clicked exists
        // do whatever row updates you want.
    }
};
```

This `mListener`  would be set to each of the `TableRow`'s `Buttons`:

```
            //...
            Button start = new Button(DashBoard.this);
            start.setOnClickListener(mListener); 
            start.setText("Start");
            start.setMaxWidth(10);
            tr.addView(start); 

            Button complete = new Button(DashBoard.this);
            complete.setOnClickListener(mListener);
            complete.setText("Complete");
            complete.setMaxWidth(10);
            tr.addView(complete); 

            Button delivered = new Button(DashBoard.this);
            delivered.setOnClickListener(mListener);
            delivered.setText("Delivered");
            delivered.setMaxWidth(10);
            tr.addView(delivered);
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to add the onclicklistners for each items within the row, instead of the row itself.

```
Button start = new Button(DashBoard.this);
start.setText("Start");
start.setMaxWidth(10);
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
      public void onClick(View pos) {
                       // update fields for start
                       // your code for update your status of the row
      }
      });
tr.addView(start); 

Button complete = new Button(DashBoard.this);
complete.setText("Complete");
complete.setMaxWidth(10);
complete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
      public void onClick(View pos) {
                       // update fields for complete
                       // your code for update your status of the row
      }
      });

tr.addView(complete); 


Button delivered = new Button(DashBoard.this);
delivered.setText("Delivered");
delivered.setMaxWidth(10);
delivered.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
      public void onClick(View pos) {
                       // update fields for delivered
                       // your code for update your status of the row
      }
      });

tr.addView(delivered);
```

edit: added the 2 other onclicklistners and added some commets

Comment: sorry can you please elaborate?

Comment: what status you want to update? you will need to add all variables you want to update within the onclick of the delivered button/start/continue